# MYSQL select 3 random records where at least one record-field has certain value

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I am trying to select 3 random records from a table, provided that the result should include at least one record with a value 'number' that is greater than 3.

Example table:

```
+--------+-------+--------+
| ID     | name  | number |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 1      | name1 | 5      |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 2      | name2 | 0      |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 3      | name3 | 2      |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 4      | name4 | 7      |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 5      | name5 | 9      |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 6      | name6 | 1      |
+--------+-------+--------+
| etc... |       |        |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

So a result could be records with ID's: 1,2 and 6. Or 1,4 and 9. But NOT 2,3 and 6, because that result does not include at least one record where 'number' > 3.

I tried this, but it fails to return results that always include at least one record with a value that is > 3:

```
SELECT name, number  FROM   table
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT number FROM table
   WHERE  number > 3
   ) 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

I think I'm on the wrong track.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thats not RANDOM then

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Specifically in the case of 'random' results, it's useful to provide 2 or 3 examples which satisfy the desired result, and one or two which don't.

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly. I tried to provide an example of the table, but it messed up the format on screen. In the link you provided I found out about the " ascii data table generator tool", so I'll try again  Bear with me, I'm learning ;)

Comment: You paste it in.... We will fix it...... you can then see what we did to format it correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a CTE that creates all the possible combinations to select from by using cross join:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    n1.id id1, n1.name name1, n1.number number1,
    n2.id id2, n2.name name2, n2.number number2,
    n3.id id3, n3.name name3, n3.number number3
  FROM numbers n1 CROSS JOIN numbers n2 CROSS JOIN numbers n3
  WHERE 
    (n1.number > 3 OR n2.number > 3 OR n3.number > 3)
    AND n1.id <> n2.id AND n1.id <> n3.id AND n3.id <> n2.id
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
)

SELECT id1 id, name1 name, number1 number FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT id2 id, name2 name, number2 number FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT id3 id, name3 name, number3 number FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=342d47ab465eff0508785b7baab65fd2)

Comment: Thanks forpas. That's an impressive query.. There is one remaining issue: while I iterated the demo, I noticed that the same records can be selected twice (or more) in one go. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: *the same records can be selected twice (or more) in one go* I don't understand what you mean. Each time you run the query you get 3 rows chosen randomly. Is there a possibility that 2 consecutive runs will produce the same 3 rows? Yes there is.

Comment: No, I mean you can get two times the same record (same ID) in one run...

Comment: Ok, the real problem was the parentheses in the WHERE clause of the cte. I edited.